# Identification of software

Tags: software-recommendation, wacom

I recently bought a Wacom and wanted to get into online tutoring.

I came across this video of a tutor teaching on o software with this particular type of pen.

Now I tried to search for that particular software but I couldn't find any. It would be really grateful if anybody of you could recognize this particular pen which is associated with the software.

[image]

Here is the video , it might help in identification .

https://youtu.be/w84RU7am_dE

Here's a snippet of the video:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you simply **ask** Launchpad IIT (the video producer)? Google their name and they have Facebook pages and other contact options.

Comment: I did but no one seems to respond. It's very frustrating when one creator doesn't help another newcomer.

Comment: Well, based on the opening of the video.. he's on a Mac and using some video editing software. I'm not versed enough in video software to recognize the UI. Could be iMovie, Adobe Premier, After Effects, Final Cut, or *anything* else......

Comment: His videos are broadcasted live so I don't think a video editing software is used. I think he uses a software for writing and a screen recorder to project it live on YouTube.

Comment: Okay I'm wrong... good luck searching. I mean the UI is right there at the beginning of the video.....

Comment: Do you know any SubReddits where I can post this

Comment: @scott do you have a Mac cuz I think the cursor type is from Mac Notes. I read about it and it says that you can sketch on attachments in Mac Notes.

Comment: https://youtu.be/YIyZ7p04T8o.              57:49

Comment: I am a Mac user. No clue what "Mac Notes" is and sorry, but I'm really not interested in solving this for you.

Comment: Oh ok . No problem.

Comment: Check if OpenBoard https://openboard.ch/index.en.html is near enough. It's available for Win, Mac and Linux. It's freeware.

Comment: Not the same software but thanks a ton , will you use this software for the time being.

Comment: There's also plenty of other whiteboard software available. Search for it. Some of them need a certain computer and some must be paid.

Comment: Found it , it's "NOTABILITY" for Mac

Comment: So, insert it as an answer and accept it after few days to close the case as solved.

Answer (score 0):

The software used is "Notability" available on Mac.

Comment: Hi @Lucian , I didn't understand what you are trying to say as I am relatively new here. So , can you please elaborate so that I can do the needful.